# Web to lead creating duplicate leads

Tags: duplicate-management, web2lead

Can any one please help me in below scenario,
We have implemented web to lead functionality in our project. from this duplicate leads are getting created. How can I figure out reasons for this ?

Comment: Do you have any code running on inbound leads? Are any other records being created?

Comment: We are using Pardot in production. I am not much aware about that. I checked affected duplicate lead records - Only Pardot URL value is different. Created By , Last Modified By rest all values are same..Except PardotURL. Also I noticed one more thing here, Lead fields Source value is '06/29/18 10:49PM' but this field is Picklist field. Does this means data is uploaded by Dataloader ?

Comment: Hmm... not necessarily Dataloader but that does not seem correct. I suspect the issue is in the code on your web2lead form and not in SF directly.

Comment: can you please let me know, where do I need to check that ?

Comment: Wherever a lead might go to submit their information... probably your company website? If you have a web developer speak with them... if not then whoever manages company IT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99% sure your web team implemented the form poorly.
The standard form just doesn't bug, or at least not in that manner.

Either that or someone is pressing the POST button multiple times, which you should prevent in browser.